# Modular exponentiation when divisor is smaller

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to calculate $(a^b) \bmod c$. Also, $a$ and $b$, both are greater than $c$. Now I know that I can replace $a$ in the given expression by $a \mod c$ which will make the calculations easier:
    $$(a \bmod c)^b \bmod c$$

But can the same reduction be done for $b$? That is, can $b$ be changed to $b \bmod c$ to simplify the calculations?

Comment: No, not in general. E.g. $2^5 = 32 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$. If you assume that $\gcd(a,c)=1$ you can use Euler's theorem.

Comment: If gcd$(a,c)=1$ you can use Euler's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem to get a lower exponent $b$ mod $\varphi(c)$ because $a^{\varphi(c)}\equiv 1$ mod $c$. Please use latex commands next time.

Answer (score 1):

No the same can not be done for $c$. Try comparing $2^4$ and $2^1$ modulo $3$.
If $a$ and $c$ are coprime then you can use [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) and reduce $b$ modulo $\phi(c)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

If $a=d\cdot e$, where $d|c$ and $e$ is coprime to $c$ you can calculate $e^b$ by the above method and so the problem is reduced to calculating $d^b$. That's a bit more subtle. There you can use the prime factorisation of $c=\prod p_i^{e_i}$ and $d=\prod p_i^{b_i}$ and use the Chinese remainder theorem $\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}=\prod \mathbb{Z}/p^e_i\mathbb{Z}$. If you need more details on that please comment.